# Lemon bread issue

Tags: baking, food-science

using my standing mixer, I creamed the butter and sugar, added the eggs, one by one.  Then added some lemon juice, the batter became grainy.  I wonder if my lemon bread will be successful ?  ( I went ahead and added the dry flour mixture.

Comment: While we don't serve as a site to FIND recipes, questions like this are unanswerable without you providing the recipe you were following (and that is not only acceptable, it's encouraged.) And by now, 47 minutes later, you should have the answer out of your oven.

Comment: Sounds like a little bit of curdling... not always bad - some recipes tell you to expect it but there's no way for us to really know.

Comment: This is a standard quick bread recipe. Really, no recipe is needed. They are all built the same way using the muffin method. It's a fine question.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR You should be fine.

Lemon bread, banana bread, etc are quick breads. They are made using the "muffin method". As you said, fat and sugar are creamed together, emulsified with egg, and then incorporated into the dry ingredients.

The fat and sugar are creamed to incorporate air that will help define the final texture. Sometimes the emulsion doesn't form correctly. As you noticed, the lemon caused your batter to separate.

It's ok. You can mix in the dry ingredients. I would expect that the broken emulsion would affect the final texture- but the times that this has happened to me I didn't notice any problems with the final product.

Remember not to over mix the dry and wet ingredients. You don't want a lot of gluten in this type of "bread".